# A Deep CNN model delivering better results with standardization, when compared with normalization

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, training, normalization

I developed a deep CNN model, based on the architecture discussed [in this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329792334_DeepAnT_A_Deep_Learning_Approach_for_Unsupervised_Anomaly_Detection_in_Time_Series), to generate predictions for time series data. My training data is shown in the figure below:

[image]

In order to train the model, I tested two approaches. The first one where I normalize the data between 0 and 1, and in the second one I standardize the data based on the approach discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174823/how-to-apply-standardization-normalization-to-train-and-testset-if-prediction-i).

I noticed that in my case, standardization performs far far better than normalization (which gave me a practically flat line as predictions) for generating the predictions. I was wondering if there is any usually suspected general reason for why this could be the case, or is it just that one method works well for a particular type of problem?